# Rails remove Query String from ckeditor assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor in my application. It works find in development environment but I am getting 404 error in production.

```
GET http://www.valleyedu.com.np/assets/ckeditor/config.js?t=GB8C 404 (Not Found)
GET http://www.valleyedu.com.np/assets/ckeditor/skins/moono-lisa/editor.css?t=GB8C 404 (Not Found) 
GET http://www.valleyedu.com.np/assets/ckeditor/lang/en.js?t=GB8C (404 (Not Found)
```

And if i remove the query string the js and css file loads up.

What is the problem. Please help me to fix it.

The gem i am using is `gem 'ckeditor', github: 'galetahub/ckeditor'`

application.js

```
//= require ckeditor/init
```

application.html.erb

```
<script>
    var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/assets/ckeditor/';
</script>
```